# AngularJS errors in IE8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I am working with a new angular app and need to make it backward compatible to IE8. From what it looks like it loads in my routing info, loads the template (to a point) but in the concole log i see the following error.

> TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method `<div
>   class=ng-scope ng-view>`

This is what my index html page looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="ng-app" ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <!--Add dependencies-->
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" src="bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.createElement('header');
            document.createElement('nav');
            document.createElement('menu');
            document.createElement('section');
            document.createElement('article');
            document.createElement('aside');
            document.createElement('footer');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header class="header header-fixed">
                <section class="navbar navbar-inverse docs-navbar-primary">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-7" style="color:white; margin-top:14px;">Thinflash: Fullscreen Demo</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </header>
            <section role="main" class="container main-body">
                <div ng-view></div>
            </section>
            <!--Add AngularJs Files-->
            <script src="swfObject.js"></script>
            <script src="app.js"></script>
            <script src="appControllers.js"></script>
            <script src="thinflash.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Template.html :

```
<div ng-controller="thinflash.controllers.playback">
    <div ng-controller="app.controllers.fullscreen">
        <div class="mainWrapper" id="stageWrapper">
            <label>SWF Object Display </label>
            <div class="swfWrapper" style="width:320px; height:240px;" id="swfStage">
                <div class="tf-container" tf-swf tf-interface="flashInterface" tf-src="thin.swf" tf-min-version="11.0.0"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
             <form role="form">
                 <!-- Video Playback Controls -->
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="form-group col-md-7">
                         <label>Select Preloaded Video:</label> 
                         <select class="form-control" ng-model="myVideo" ng-init="myVideo = videos[2]" ng-change="changeVideo(myVideo)" ng-options="v for v in videos"><option></option></select>
                     </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-7">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="pausePlaybackToggle()">Pause</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="playVideo()">Play</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-7">
                        <label>Volume Control:</label> 
                        <input style="width:50%;" type="range" id="slider" min="1" max="100" step="1" ng-model="volume" ng-change="changeVolume()">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <label>Size Controls:</label><br/> 
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="changeVideoSize(1)">Small</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="changeVideoSize(2)">Medium</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="changeVideoSize(3)">Large</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Again when the app loads in IE8 it appears that the template loads (or starts too ... but i get this error)

Comment: You posted the HTML, but this is a js error. Can you post that instead? Often it is because you're using unsupported array functions like indexOf etc.

Answer (score 6):

Add html5 support for IE8 by using something like [html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/) or this little snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.createElement('header');
  document.createElement('nav');
  document.createElement('menu');
  document.createElement('section');
  document.createElement('article');
  document.createElement('aside');
  document.createElement('footer');
</script>
```

## Edit

Fixing an "Object does not support this method or property" on IE can be a beast, cause it isn't telling you anything. It's not telling you what **object**, it's not telling you what **property**, it's not telling you what **method** and worst of all it's not telling you **where** this actually occurred. See the pattern? Effectively it's saying; *something bad has happened somewhere, go figure*. This is one of the reasons why everyone *loves* IE.

Adding the above snippet has probably solved a problem but then another problem popped up, which produced the same brilliant error message. Fixing this breadcrumb adventure of error messages by posting each new involved piece of *html* can take a very long time and should rather be discussed with the helpdesk of IE. *They have an answering machine telling you to upgrade to their new crappy box of other issues*. Troubleshooting this problem via Stackoverflow is like shooting satellites out of the sky with a water pistol, in the dark, blindfolded and drunk.

Some other things you might consider:

- Move the snippet to above any other script include
- Replace the snippet with html5shiv
- Downgrade the include version AngularJS. Version 1.1.5 seems to work for IE7. Version 1.3 does not support IE8 at all.
- Check the guide lines of [Angular IE compatibility](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)
- Start commenting code (javascript/html) to better isolate the part that is causing the problem. Keep in mind that multiple problems generate the **same error** message in IE.
- Upgrade to their new crappy box of other issues.

Comment: I added the above script into the Head section of my index page. The ui-bootstrap stuff seems to be working now but I still get the same error that I originally listed. Possibly there is an issue in my template when it loads . I will add it to the original post for clarification.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to take a second and answer this incase someone else has the same type of thing happen. I tried to polyFill and that didnt work so I tried running the code in IE9 while running in IE8 mode hoping to get a different error .... Voila ....

null hit the nail on the head ... it was in the JS and it was because I was doing document.addListener(). Luckily I was able to quicly decide that the functionality that this supported was not important enough to pull my hair out so i removed that line in my js...

Everything else worked .... Hopefully this can be of some help to someone in the future as IE provides stellar error messages