# Angular and IE8 reporting Type Error

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I'm having issues in IE8 displaying my angular app. It's working in IE10, Chrome Firefox but when I run it in iE I get the following error:

TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method

I was wondering if anyone had encountered anything similar. I have consulted the Angular IE8 page but the error is persisting. I was thinking that it is a problem related to the routing but I am not sure.

Comment: Hey! Can you please include minimal code required to reproduce the error?

Comment: Which version of angularjs are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS errors in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399626/angularjs-errors-in-ie8)